# C# Regex Problem

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract all table rows from an HTML page.
But using the pattern `@"<tr>([\w\W]*)</tr>"` is not working.
It's giving one result which is first occurence of `<tr>` to last occurrence of `</tr>`.
But I want every occurrence of `<tr>...</tr>` value.
Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do agree with Mark: you should to use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library.

About your regex, you should to go with something like:

```
@"<tr>([\s\S]*?)</tr>"
```

That's a non greedy pattern, and you should to get one match for every TR.

Comment: Another question... Can you provide me any link or book name where I can learn this all regex [C#] property properly ?

Answer (score 5):

`[\w\W]*` matches [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) so it will match from the first `<tr>` to the last `</tr>`.

A regex approach won't work well because HTML is not a regular language. If you really wanted to try to use a lazy modifier such as `"<tr>(.*?)</tr>"` with the [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) flag, however this isn't guaranteed to work in all cases.

For parsing HTML you need an HTML parser. Try [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Comment: And we all know what happens when you try to parse html with a regex... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Another question is there anyway so that I can do it using regex ?

Comment: This page shows a quick example of how the HTML Agility Pack library can be used: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples